# How to turn cobblestone and sand into dirt in FTB Mindcrack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a compressed plantball machine that makes compressed plantbals from dirt but i don't have a lot of dirt left and i was wondering if i could make dirt from either couble and sand or both to get me more dirt.

I would prefer using buildcraft and industrialcraft items/blocks only but if that can't be done with those i can still switch.

Is this possible and how?

PS. I have all EU that you will need, don't worry about power usage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get dirt from composting Weed (IC2), one dirt for 32 pieces. Harvest it with weeding trowel from crops. (one fully grown weed can yield 7 pieces)....BUT it needs to have new versions of IC2 for 1.7.10, otherwise....

But maybe second way, dirt is one of the scrapbox drops, hm?

Or you can always use Minetweaker to add some recipes.

Comment: mhm, i run minecaft 1.4.7 becau8se that's the latest mindcrack pack version...

Comment: Well, then try other thingies as Minetweaker or scrapbox drops...
With 1.4.7 you miss really big bunch of things that are normal in younger versions than 2 years :)
For me it would be easier to make 1.7.10 modpack with same mods, but that is up to you.